# excel vba experimenting with functions and arrays

Tags: arrays, function, vba, excel

I am experimenting with something:

There is a list with names, and what I would like to do, is to read the cell values in an array (this part works) than run a check for every cell in the worksheet and if a given cell is the same as a string inside an array, do something.

But unfortunatly I get the "type mismatch" error.

Ps. I know this doesn't make much sense and I could to that something inside the server function, but belive me I have my reasons. :-)

Edit: fixed a few things, now it looks like this (now I get the object doesn't support this property of method)

If it helps, you can also try it. You just need to add a cell with the name "Servers" and under it write some random words. Right now it should write in msgbox "ok" x times, where x is the number of rows you wrote in, under the cell, named "Servers"

1

```
'server name
Function server(ByVal issrvname As String)
Dim j As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

For Each c In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells

Dim srvname() As String
j = 0
    If c.Cells.Value = "Servers" Then
    y = c.Column: x = c.Row + 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(x, y))
        ReDim Preserve srvname(0 To j) As String
        srvname(j) = Cells(x, y).Value
        x = x + 1
        j = j + 1
        Loop
    End If
Next c

For Each c In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells
    If IsInArray(c.Cell.Value, srvname) Then
        issrvname = True
    Else
        issrvname = False
  End If
Next c

End Function
```

2

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

3

```
Sub test()


Dim c As Range

For Each c In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells

    If server(c) = True Then
   MsgBox "ok"
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: please highlight the rows where the error shows up

Comment: it does now show up, when I run the sub test() an msgbox appears saying: run-time error 13: Type mismatch

Comment: After the "Do", add `Debug.Print x, y`. After the `For Each cell`, add `Debug.Print cell.address`. This will narrow it down. Then you can `Stop` at the problem area and single-cycle (F8). See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can condense your functions:

First you need to include your *Array generating block* to your main sub.
Including it in the Function *server* is slowing code execution because it needs to generate the array in every call of the *server* Function

**Edit1:** This is tried in tested now. I've re-written your function and improve your sub a bit.

```
Sub test()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim c As Range, c1 As Range
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim i As Long '~~> added it just to check how many is shown in MsgBox

    For Each c In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells
        '~~> generate array if "Servers" is encountered
        If c.Value = "Servers" Then
            Dim srvname() As String
            j = 0
            y = c.Column: x = c.Row + 1
            With Sheets("Topology").UsedRange
                Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, y))
                    ReDim Preserve srvname(j)
                    srvname(j) = .Cells(x, y).Value
                    x = x + 1
                    j = j + 1
                Loop
            End With
            '~~> use the generated Array of values here
            i = 1
            For Each c1 In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells
                If IsInArray(c1.Value, srvname) Then
                    MsgBox "ok" & i
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next c1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

Here's the new function: (actually, you don't need it, you can call the *Match* function directly in main Sub)

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Maybe you do this just for testing? I just thought that the sheet you use to generate the array must be different from the sheet you want to compare the server names.

Comment: you are a genius, there are some other problems with the script as well. I try to get it working asap

Comment: _Maybe you do this just for testing? I just thought that the sheet you use to generate the array must be different from the sheet you want to compare the server names._ 

you are right, I want to use this on other worksheets as well. but if this part works, the rest will be easy. :-)

Comment: @Divin3 You already used it in a *Function* so same can be done in a *Sub*. Say you have a *Sub* named **Test2**, you can also pass it ByRef. You create the sub like this: Sub Test2(arr As Variant) then make a call on that sub in your main sub.

Comment: there is a problem that I dont understand. It fills the array with the values of the next column

Comment: I realized that i, has to be 0 instead of 1, because 0 is the first element of the array, but I dont understand, how does it gets to the next row, and why I have to write  `y = c.Column -1` to get it working right

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be that you define c as a range in Test, but call server with c when server is expecting a boolean.

Comment: @Divin3 I think above answer by RowanC nails it. Changing `Function server(ByVal issrvname As Boolean)` to this `Function server(issrvname)` will do the trick. But of course, you can be explicit with the `ByVal/ByRef` as well as the type. Like `Function server(ByVal issrvname As String)`.

Comment: It would help OP (and make him/her happy) if you could provide a fix to your identified issue/problem. :)

Comment: this helped, but now I get object doesen't support this property of method